# How to pass values entered into inputs contained within a Bootstrap modal (form) to an HTML table?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal

So i currently have a modal that prompts the user to select an image (file input), enter their name (text input) and their surname (text input). After doing so, they click an "Add to table" button within the modal, that is suppose to add the above inputs into their respective data cells within an HTML table. I am unsure on how i would pass these input values to the tables data cells? Is there a specific keyword that i would need to use?

Table (HTML):

```
  <tr>
          <th scope="row">1</th>
          <td> ... image input here ... </td>
          <td> ... name input here ... </td>
          <td> ... surname input here ... </td>
        </tr>
```

Modal (Bootstrap):

```
  <div class="modal-body">
          <form class="" action="index.html" method="post">
            <form>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="insertImage">Insert Image</label>
                <input type="file" class="form-control-file" id="Insert Image" accept="image/x-png,image/gif,image/jpeg" aria-describedby="inputHelp">
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="addName">Name</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="addName">
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="addSurname">Surname</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="addSurname">
              </div>
            </form>
          </form>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Add to Table</button>
        </div>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: you can set a className at the inputs and when the user confirm the modal, capture them and insert to the table with jquery (bootstrap use it) like this  var name = $(".nameInput").val(); $("td").html(name);

Comment: Whether your expected output is like this https://codepen.io/Maniraj_Murugan/pen/PoqJOrg ??

Comment: yes, exactly like that. But while using jQuery.

Comment: @SeventhWarhawk, Really I am not familiar with jquery and not a big fan of it.. I always follow lets do it in Vanilla than depending on a library... Anyhow If it resolves your issue, I will post it as answer.. If you want for jquery solution then you can wait for..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is a quick start for you to get you going with jquery based on @Maniraj Murugan code (thanks I was too lazy to create a new example).
Just replace the JS code with something like this:

```
$("#addtotable").on('click', function() {
    if($("#addName").val() !== '' && $("#addSurname").val() !== ''){
        let row = '<tr> <td>' + $("#addName").val() + '</td> <td>' + ("#addSurname").val() + '</td> </tr>'
        $('tbody').append(row)
    }
});
```

https://codepen.io/greenn_anbu/pen/qBdPxNe

hope it helped